# Get Occurrences of Letters in A String

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to count occurrences of letters in a string and almost got the result using the below code snippet:

```
public static void GetNoofLetters()
{
    string str = "AAAAABBCCCDDDD";
    int count = 1;
    
    char[] charVal = str.ToCharArray();
    
    List<string> charCnt = new List<string>();
     
    string concat = "";
    
    //Getting each letters using foreach loop
    foreach (var ch in charVal)
    {
        int index = charCnt.FindIndex(c => c.Contains(ch.ToString())); //Checks if there's any existing letter in the list
            
        if(index >= 0) //If letter exists, then count and replace the last value 
        {
            count++;                 
            charCnt[charCnt.Count - 1] = count.ToString() + ch.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            charCnt.Add(ch.ToString()); //If no matching letter exists, then add it to the list initially 
            count = 1;
        } 
    }
    
    foreach (var item in charCnt)
    {
        concat += item;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(concat.Trim());
}
```

The code works for the given input sample and returns output as: **5A2B3C4D**. Simple is that.

But say I've the following input: **Second input sample**

```
string str = "AAAAABBCCCDDDDAA";
```

**Expected output**:

```
5A2B3C4D2A
```

With the above code that I've returns the output as follows:

```
5A2B3C6A
```

The above actually occurred for the below code snippet:

```
if(index >= 0) //If letter found, then count and replace the last value 
{
   count++;                 
   charCnt[charCnt.Count - 1] = count.ToString() + ch.ToString();
}
```

Is there any better idea that I can resolve to get the expected output for the second input sample? I can understand, am close enough and may be missing something that's simple enough.

Code sample: [Count Occurrences of Letters](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aIP0iv)

Comment: You could use MoreLinq's `GroupAdjacent`,  `string.Concat(str.GroupAdjacent(c => c).Select(grp => $"{grp.Count()}{grp.Key}"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended with the following code sample:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string str = "AAAAABBCCCDDDDAABBBBAABB";
    int count = 1;
    
    char[] charVal = str.ToCharArray();
    
    List<string> charCnt = new List<string>();
    charCnt.Add("");
    
    string concat = "";
    
    //Getting each letters using foreach loop
    foreach (var ch in charVal)
    {
        var lastItem = charCnt.LastOrDefault();
        if (lastItem.EndsWith((ch.ToString()))) //If letter exists, then count and replace the last value 
        {
            count++;
            charCnt[charCnt.Count - 1] = count.ToString() + ch.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            charCnt.Add(ch.ToString()); //If no matching letter exists, then add it to the list initially 
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    foreach (var item in charCnt)
    {
        concat += item; //Concatenate items from the list
    }

    Console.WriteLine(concat.Trim());
}
```

Here's a woking sample: [Get Occurrences of Letters in A String](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Spij80)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't we just loop over `value` and count? We can have two possibilities:

1. When character `c` doesn't equal to `current` (we have the different character) we should write down the previous sequence and start a new one
2. Otherwise, add `1` to `count`

**Code:**

```
private static string Compress(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;

  char current = '\0';
  int count = 0; 

  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(2 * value.Length); 

  foreach (char c in value) {
    if (count != 0 && c != current) {
      result.Append(count);
      result.Append(current);

      count = 0;
    }

    current = c;
    count += 1;
  }

  result.Append(count);
  result.Append(current);

  return result.ToString();
}
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zpf9pM) yourself

Comment: very similar to what I was going to post.  Nice